# How to split up a string by every new line and put each line into a separate array entry in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

My question is very simple and I am very new to PowerShell but I'm just wondering if there is a easy way to split a string by each line and add the contents of each line into a separate array entry.

Answer (score 4):

To complement [Don Cruickshank's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46270530/45375):

`` "`n" `` expands to a **LF character only** (***Unix*-style**, Unicode code point `U+000A`), but your input may use **CRLF sequences** (`` "`r`n" ``, ***Windows*-style**, Unicode code points `U+000D` and `U+000A`) as **newlines (line breaks)**.

While a given *platform*'s native newline character [sequence] is reflected in `[Environment]::Newline`, there's no guarantee that a given *input* (file)'s newlines uses it.

Notably, script-embedded here-strings (e.g., `@"<newline>...<newline>"@`) use whatever newline format the enclosing script file was saved with - and when reading scripts for execution, PowerShell accepts *both* LF-only and CRLF files on *all* platforms it supports.

**Therefore, the most robust form to split a string into lines by newlines is the following idiom**, which takes advantage of the fact that the `-split` operator by default accepts a *regular expression* as the split criterion:

```
 $str -split '\r?\n'       # returns array of lines contained in $str
```

The above handles input with both LF-only (`\n`) and CRLF (`\r\n`) newlines correctly,
because `\r?\n` matches each `\n` (LF) optionally (`?`) preceded by an `\r` (CR).

Answer (score 3):

The help system for PowerShell contains lots of useful information (type `help` to get started.)

Use the `-split` operator to split a string. PowerShell uses the backtick character (`` ` ``) for escape codes and so it would look like this:

```
$str -split "`n"
```

For example we can define a string and call `Length` on that string to get the Length (in characters):

```
PS C:\> $str = "One`nTwo`nThree"

PS C:\> $str
One
Two
Three

PS C:\> $str.Length
13
```

Now we'll create an array where that string is split into lines and get the length of the resulting array. Note that in PowerShell, arrays are shown one item per line and so it's appears just like the earlier result in this case!

```
PS C:\> $arr = $str -split "`n"

PS C:\> $arr
One
Two
Three

PS C:\> $arr.Length
3
```

PowerShell can be confusing at first. One trick is to convert data structures to JSON to see what's going on until you get used to it.

```
PS C:\> $str | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
"One\nTwo\nThree"

PS C:\> $arr | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
["One","Two","Three"]
```